# how to add radiobutton to cursor adapter which works like radiobutton in a radio group ie grouping the radiobutton

Tags: android

## editstudent.xml

```
  LinearLayout 

      ListView
           android:id="@android:id/list"        
      ListView

  LinearLayout
```

## editstudentlist

```
  LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"  --  TOP Linear

       LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"  -- sub Linear

           Tex0tView  android:id="@+id/enlist_tv_Name"  TextView

           TextView   android:id="@+id/enlist_tv_class" TextView

       LinearLayout -- sub Linear

       RadioButton  android:id="@+id/enList_rb_Id"   RadioButton

  LinearLayout --  TOP Linear
```

## StudentActivity

```
StudentActivity extends ListActivity {

    setContentView(R.layout.editstudent);

    //get the data from database

    Cursor cursor = noMgr.getAllStudent();

    String[] columns= {StdentHelper.KEY_NAME,StdentHelper.KEY_CLASS, StdentHelper.KEY_ID};
    int[] to=new int[]{R.id.enlist_tv_name, R.id.enlist_tv_class, R.id.enList_rb_id};

    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.editstudentlist, cursor, columns, to);

    this.setListAdapter(scAdapter);

}
```

Here, there is a custom layout (editnumberlist.xml) with two text boxes and one radio button. It's been added to (editstudent.xml) using `simpleCursorAdapter` and it's working.

But I want the radio button to act like it's in the radio group (e.g. single selection at a time). Another question I have is how can I give the `StudentHelper.KEY_ID` to the radio button that should not be shown at runtime / execution time. Also how should I get the value of `StudentHelper.KEY_ID` in `onListItemClick()` function.

Does any one know how can I implement this?

Comment: Try to create a custom adapter class which extends the "simpleCursorAdapter", set a flag in your code... that flag will save the index of currently selected radio item... on click event of radio button, reset all others and set the first one